# I am trying to understand how linked list work

Tags: python

Trying to work thru codesignal's linked list tutorial, but having trouble understanding the following code. I do get what each line does but not why we `tmp = l` assign `l` to `tmp` and at the end check `l`.

```py
# Definition for singly-linked list:
# class ListNode(object):
#   def __init__(self, x):
#     self.value = x
#     self.next = None
#
def removeKFromList(l, k):
    tmp = l
    while tmp:
        if tmp.next and tmp.next.value == k:
            tmp.next = tmp.next.next
        else:
            tmp = tmp.next

    if l and l.value == k:
        return l.next
    else:
        return l
```

where `l` is a linked list

`l = [3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

`k = 3`

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Your code seems not right to me. Did you write this your own?

Comment: `tmp` is a kind of pointer to the currently processed item in the list (actually the item before the currently processed one). It starts at the beginning (`l`) and continues until it becomes `None` (end of list).

Comment: @knh190 No, its a solution.

Comment: @MichaelButscher does that mean that by going thru the linked list `l` and "skipping" the value of `k` (if found)  we effectively removing `k`?

Comment: @knh190 that is why I am asking the question, I never used linked lists before and I am trying to understand them correctly in order to use them - correctly.

Comment: @StephanOsterburg Items with value `k` are removed by connecting (through the `next` field) the item before that (which connects to `k`-item yet) to the item after that. The `k`-item isn't then part of the list anymore.

Answer (score 0):

At the end, you check `l` because the while loop never checks if the first element in the linked list is the element you are supposed to remove. In the example data you provided, if that check wasn't there, the 3 would not be removed.

`tmp = l` is there to make a "copy" of `l` so that it can go though every element in the list without forgetting what the first element was. This is tied in to the check at the end, because if you ran the while loop directly on `l`, you would no longer be able to check the first element.

Answer (score 0):

The key thing to understand here is that assigning a variable that points to an object to another variable, gives you a copy of the reference, not the object. So, if `a` is an instance of object type `MyClass`, then doing `b = a` doesn't create a copy of `a`, but instead it makes it so that `a` and `b` now point to the same object.

In your example code, `tmp = l` causes `tmp` to point to the object pointed to by `l`. `tmp` is then used to run over the list and make the required changes, thus modifying the object (the head node of the list) pointed to by `l`, as well as the following nodes, while `l` keeps pointing at the head node.

It's not a very good piece of code though and the naming is confusing, given naming conventions and built-ins in Python. But I understand that's not your fault.

Answer (score 0):

It's using 2 checks to filter out element `k` - removing any nodes that has a value of `k`.

First time `tmp` is used to loop through the list to unlink any node (*except the first node*) that has `tmp.value == k` using:

```
tmp.next = tmp.next.next # tmp.next is not in the list then
```

While at this time your first node is still held by `l` and not checked.

So it checks for the head (the first node) at the end.